# php removechild remove two childs

Tags: php, html, dom

Like the title said i've got a problem with the php removeChild function

I ve got this script looping over html tags

```php
$list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tag");

//charge et supprimme les tags
while($lst = $list->item(0)) {

    $tgs = ucfirst($lst->getAttribute("type"));
    array_push($test, $tgs);
    $tg = new $tgs($dom, $lst, false);

    $tg->render();
    var_dump("--------- 1 ---------");
    for ($i=0; $i < $list->count(); $i++) {
        var_dump($list->item($i)->getAttribute("type"));
    }

    // var_dump($list[0]->parentNode->nodeName);

    $lst->parentNode->removeChild($lst); //this line

    var_dump("--------- 2 ---------");
    for ($i=0; $i < $list->count(); $i++) {
        var_dump($list->item($i)->getAttribute("type"));
    }
    $list = $dom->getElementsByTagName("tag");
}
```

and this html file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <tag type="includes" file="header" />
    </header>
    <main class="test container">
        <div class="bloc_principal">
            <div class="cover-black">
                <div class="bloc_principal_titre">
                    <h1>L'actualitÃ© de nos campus...</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="test2">
                    <h2 id="titre-home">Ceci est un magnifique titre</h2>
                    <p class="p-home">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed
                        do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                        nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
                        in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                        cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                    <div class="bloc-plus">
                        En savoir plus
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <h3 id="titre-between">Articles récents</h3>
        <div class="row articles">
            <tag type="loop" for="posts" limit="6">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="article column-categorie">
                        <h4 class="title">
                            <loop column="title" />
                        </h4>
                        <div class="etiquettes">
                            <span class="cat">
                                <loop column="categorie" />
                            </span>
                            <span class="date">
                                <loop column="date" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text">
                            <loop column="content" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </tag>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <tag type="includes" file="footer" />
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

most of it is working fine.

but for some reason the function `$lst->parentNode->removeChild($lst);` remove both

- `<tag type="loop">`
- `<footer><tag type="includes"></footer>`

that are my last childs existing when it should only remove the `<tag type="loop">`

when i var_dump $lst->parentNode i get the correct parent for deleting my tag (`<div class="row articles">`)

Comment: I don’t see you checking for the parent node or limiting the element selection to a specific parent anywhere, so based on what should this _not_ remove just every single element named `tag` in the first place …?

Comment: in the while I select the first one

Comment: First thing I noticed is that your while loop does not contain an iterator. Why use a loop if you are not using an iterator? As of right now, the while loop will work exactly the same as an if-statement.

Comment: because some tags can have some other tags in it so I have to keep checking for more until the document don't see any

Comment: Yes but you should use an iterator that stacks up infinitely until it cannot find any other element anymore, that is how loops work. As of right now `$lst` will always return to: `$dom->getElementsByTagName("tag")->item(0)`. The number `0` here should contain an iteration field (e.g. `$i` or `$iteration`) that will be incremented in a loop.

Comment: thats what I want, I delete them in the loop so if there is an iterator all my tags aren't going to be processed

Comment: _“in the while I select the first one”_ - and after you removed that element, the next one will become the new first one, so you select that then in the next loop iteration ... NodeList are _live_, they always reflect the current state of the document.

Comment: and? I know that i always select the first one in the document because I delete them on after another at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found that the html was badly formatted and a `</div>` wasn't placed at the correct line, so my last `<tag type="includes">` was deleted by the precedent one